# I want to sort a List of object using date which is a attribute of object. I used Collection.sort but not worked

Tags: sorting, spring-boot, collections

```
private List<Activity> sortByDate(List<Activity> activityList){

    System.out.println(activityList.size());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Collections.sort(activityList, new Comparator<Activity>() {
        public int compare(Activity a1, Activity a2) {
            System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            int result = 0;
            try {
                result =  sdf.parse(a2.getDate()).compareTo(sdf.parse(a1.etDate()));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                //The date should be validated to (dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss) this format in front end before add to the db
            }
            return result;
        }
    });
    return activityList;
}
```

This is the method that I have created. The first SOP printed 2 as output so activityList is not empty, but the second SOP line wasn't executed. The code that I use to call the sortByDate method is below. I can't figure out why Collections.sort is not executed.

```
public List<RetrieveActivity> getPage(int pageNumber) throws CustomException{

    PageRequest request = new PageRequest(pageNumber - 1, PAGESIZE, Sort.Direction.ASC, "id");
    List<Activity> tempList =  repository.findAll(request).getContent();
    if (tempList.size() > 0) {
        tempList = sortByDate(tempList);
    }
```

But Activity model class has the date attribute as a String. But the thing is, the line 'System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");' was never executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you're using (`"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"`) doesn't maintain order when you're moving to the string representation of the object.

Instead of using string comparison:

```
result = sdf.parse(a2.getDate()).compareTo(sdf.parse(a1.etDate()));
```

use date comparison:

```
result = a2.getDate().compareTo(a1.getDate());
```

Comment: If you are on java8, you can make it null safe using java.util.Comparator, e.g. java.util.Comparator.comparing(Activity::getDate,nullsLast(naturalOrder())).compare(a2,a1);